# Trying to generate a number that does not share a common factor with another number greater than 1 (code included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

(Update: Now fixed! Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ayd0Lx3t/30/)

I'm trying to generate a random number between 3 & 9 that doesn't share any factors with 12:

```
function gcdfunction(a, b) {  // THIS FUNCTION GENERATES THE GREATEST COMMON DIVISOR BUT I'M GETTING A CONSOLE ERROR THAT { IS AN UNEXPECTED TOKEN 
   var gcd; 
    if ( ! b) {
        return a;
    }

    return gcd(b, a % b); // I'M ALSO GETTING AN ERROR THAT THIS IS UNDEFINED
};

function randomBetween (min, max) { //THIS FUNCTION GENERATES A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN A GIVEN MIN & MAX
  var ceiling = max + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - min)) + min;
}

function GenerateRandomNumber3to9Excluding (min, max, b) { 
  var random;
  var gcd;
  do {
     random = randomBetween(min, max); 
     gcd = gcdfunction(random, b); // THIS IS INTENDED TO CALL THE GCDFUNCTION DEFINED ABOVE
  } while((gcd > 1)); // IF THE GCD > 1, IT GENERATES ANOTHER RANDOM NUMBER
  alert(random);
}
```

`var GenerateRandomNumber3to9No2 = GenerateRandomNumber3to9Excluding`(3,9,12);

Here's the link:  https://jsfiddle.net/ayd0Lx3t/23/

I feel like there's a somewhat quick fix that I'm just not seeing; any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *"I'M ALSO GETTING AN ERROR THAT THIS IS UNDEFINED"* that is because **it is** undefined as you declared it as `var gcd;` and did not set any value to it.

Comment: So you're trying to generate `5` or `7`? Just do `Math.random() < 0.5 ? 5 : 7`.

Comment: How would I modify that though? I just added `var gcd;` in there to see if it would address the undefined error. Would you mind recommending how I might fix this? Noob here, clearly..using examples like this to learn.

Comment: @Paulpro No, I have to do it this way because I'm going to use this repeatedly for various other numbers.

Comment: calling gcd is not a function, you probably mean gcdfunction() on line 7

Comment: @dGRAMOP That did it!!! I figured it was a simple fix like that. If you write that up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks so much (Of course, I had to get rid of `var gcd;` in line  2, as well.

Comment: writing it up now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the recursion: gcd is an undefined variable declared on line 2, you probably mean to call the function gcdfunction

Here's your new code

```
function gcdfunction(a, b) {  // THIS FUNCTION GENERATES THE GREATEST COMMON DIVISOR BUT I'M GETTING A CONSOLE ERROR THAT { IS AN UNEXPECTED TOKEN 
   var gcd; 
    if ( ! b) {
        return a;
    }

    return gcdfunction(b, a % b); // I'M ALSO GETTING AN ERROR THAT THIS IS UNDEFINED
};

function randomBetween (min, max) { //THIS FUNCTION GENERATES A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN A GIVEN MIN & MAX
  var ceiling = max + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - min)) + min;
}

function GenerateRandomNumber3to9Excluding (min, max, b) { 
  var random;
  var gcd;
  do {
     random = randomBetween(min, max); 
     gcd = gcdfunction(random, b); // THIS IS INTENDED TO CALL THE GCDFUNCTION DEFINED ABOVE
  } while((gcd > 1)); // IF THE GCD > 1, IT GENERATES ANOTHER RANDOM NUMBER
  alert(random);
}
```